# proper way of sending values between classes

Tags: c#, multithreading, variables

i've asked a question before but sounds that i didn't explain it in good way so here is the codes of the buggest part
class packet handler (receive information from packet and store them at x,y and there is struct which accept 2 ushort ref so once i define an object it change the value of the variables i send)

```
public class PacketHandler : GUI
    {
        GameUser role;
        public PacketHandler(GameUser who)
        {
            role = who;
        }
        ushort Actualx, Actualy;
        public PacketHandler(ref ushort x ,ref ushort y)
        {
            x = Actualx; y = Actualy;
        }
        public unsafe void HandleServer(byte[] data)
        {
.
.
.
                        case 10010:
                            {
                                if (BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 8) == 1002)
                                {
                                    Actualx = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 24);
                                    Actualy = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 26);
                                }
                                break;
                            }
```

this get the value from packets , store them at actualx , actualy preparing to give them to any ushort ref come at the defining object parameter

here is other class

```
public class ClientBase
{
    GameUser role2;
    public ClientBase(GameUser role)
    {
        role2 = role;
        Thread T = new Thread(HuntThread) { Name = "Hunt Thread" };
        T.Start(this);
    }
.
.
.
    public void HuntThread(object Sender)
    {
        ClientBase Client = Sender as ClientBase;
        while (true)
        {
            Monster Target = GetNextkill();
            if (Target != null)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                ProxyParadise.Network.Packets.PacketHandler getxandy = new ProxyParadise.Network.Packets.PacketHandler(ref X, ref Y);
                ProxyParadise.Network.Packets.PacketStructure ps = new ProxyParadise.Network.Packets.PacketStructure();
.
.
.
```

and the real problem is i find zero at x and y , when i trace it i find zero at actualx,actualy however im sure they got a value , so i think im doing something stupid

so all in all , if u can't help me at this code or figure out what i mean then please tell me a proper way to get values from another class while using threading , thanks everyone , please some mod delete my old question , i rephrase it now in better way

Comment: It sounds to me like what you actually want is a way to update the value in the class after its been set, while still referring to the old value?  This sounds like a job for events and properties...well, that or semaphores and locks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we go:

```
    ushort Actualx, Actualy;
    public PacketHandler(ref ushort x ,ref ushort y)
    {
        x = Actualx; y = Actualy;
    }
```

You are assigning the values from the fields (which are initially zero) to the parameters, rather than the values from the parameters *to* the fields:

```
    ushort Actualx, Actualy;
    public PacketHandler(ushort x , ushort y)
    {
        Actualx = x;
        Actualy = y
    }
```

Note I removed the `ref` too; that would have had the nasty side-effect (in your original code) of wiping the by-ref variables you passed in, since the fields are zero initially.

However, what you *can't* do is *store* a "reference to a `ushort`" as a field. If you need that, the best thing to do is to drop the value onto a class, and refer to the object:

```
class Foo {
    public ushort Value {get;set;}
}
```

then any number of callers can have references to the same `Foo` object, and therefore updating one is updating all. Frankly, your `PacketHandler` would already serve in place of this `Foo`; the trick would be for multiple pieces of code to have a reference to the handler, and get their `.ActualX` / `.ActualY` *from the object*.

Comment: @AndrewRober: If this answers your question then accept it to reward the answerer!